# Etch a sketch program in processing(java) (new programmer)

Tags: java, processing

I can't figure out how to make my code create a continuous line instead of a string of dots.
first problem is that my line function is (posX,posY,posX,posY), this is creating dots, but I have no idea how to change it so that its a continuous line

```
float posX; //current mouseX position  
float posY; // current mouseY position  
float ballSpeed = 50f; //controls speed that the stylus moves  
final float OFF_SET = 250f; // allows ball to stay still if mouse is in center   of window  
void setup()  
{    
  size(500, 500);   
  posX= width/2; // next four lines of code make the stylus start in middle  
  posY=width/2;  

  background(255); //clears background once  
}  
void draw()  
{  

  drawLine(); //calls the drawLine function  
  moveStylus(); //calls the moveStylus function  
}  

void drawLine()  
{  
  line(posX, posY, posX, posY); //draws a  line starting previous to relative   mouse position and ending at to current to relative mouse position  
}  
void moveStylus()  
{  
  float moveX;   
  float moveY;  
  moveX = (mouseX-OFF_SET)/ballSpeed;  
  moveY = (mouseY-OFF_SET)/ballSpeed;  
  posX+= moveX;   
  posY+= moveY;  
  posX= max(width+1-width, posX);  // line will never leave right side of screen  
  posX = min(width-1, posX); //line will never leave left side of screen  
  posY= max(height+1-height, posY); //line will never leave bottom of screen  
  posY = min(width-1, posY); // line will never leave top of  screen  
}
```

Comment: The call of line(posX, posY, posX, posY) is worrisome.  Does it mean "draw a line starting at (posX, posY) and ending at (posX, posY)"?  Last two args probavbly should be different from the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
 line(posX, posY, posX, posY);
```

You're passing in the same coordinates for the start and end of the line, which will only draw a single point.

If you want to draw a line, you're going to have to pass in different values for the start and end. You could store the previous position in separate variables, or you could store the next position in a temporary variable, draw your line, and then update the current position by pointing it at your temporary value.

But the end goal is to pass in different values for the start and end of your lines.